# Why is #clone() not in the Cloneable interface?

Tags: java

I was reading up on performing a deep-copy of an array correctly, however I was confused about how the `#clone()` is implemented. It is a member of the `java.lang.Object` class, and yet if you read the javadocs:

> First, if the class of this object does not implement the interface Cloneable, then a CloneNotSupportedException is thrown.

So why define the `clone` method there in the first place? Surely if a method can only be used when an interface is present, you'd put the method in the interface. The `Cloneable` interface itself is empty; it is just a marker interface used by Java to ensure that using the `clone` method is legal.

Doing it this way also removes the ability to make use of generics to ensure type safety:

```
class Foo implements Cloneable { // Valid.
    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // ...
    }
}

class TypeSafeFoo implements Cloneable<TypeSafeFoo> { // Not valid.
    @Override
    public TypeSafeFoo clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Why has Java done it this way? I'm sure they have legitimate reasons, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Actually this was a design flaw as said by Joshua Bloch

Comment: This is one of the many reasons cloning is considered broken.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The cloning contract in Java dictates that each `clone` implementation must first obtain the cloned instance from `super.clone()`. This creates a chain that always ends with the call to `Object.clone`, and that method contains "magical" native-level code that makes a binary copy of the underlying raw `struct` which represents the Java object. If this mechanism didn't exist, `clone` would fail to be polymorphic: the `Object.clone` method produces an instance of whatever class it is called on; this cannot be reproduced without native code.

This is why the `Object.clone` method could not have been avoided. `Cloneable` *could* have contained a `clone` method, but it would create issues regarding the `throws` clause. The way it stands, you are free to declare `clone` with no declared exceptions, or to declare arbitrary exceptions. This flexibility would not be possible if the method was already declared in the interface.

Bear in mind that Generics would be of little use for cloning: imagine `protected T clone()` in `Object`: where would `T` come from? Would we need `Object<T>` and force every class to be parameterized on itself, all just to make this semi-deprecated mechanism work a tiny bit better? Keep also in mind that this code is perfectly legal:

```
public class TheMightyOne implements Cloneable {
   @Override public TheMightyOne clone() {
     return (TheMightyOne) super.clone();
   }
}
```

You can call it:

```
TheMightyOne one = new TheMightyOne();
TheMightyOne two = one.clone(); // do downcasts needed
```

Comment: Couldn't most of this have been avoided by making the magic clone method static? `Object.clone(Cloneable item)`. Then anything implementing `Cloneable` would pass `this` to `Object.clone`. This could have easily worked with generics too.

Answer (score 6):

To deal with creating the clone and basic field copying, clone needs to inherit a method implementation.  A Cloneable class can appear anywhere in the hierarchy, and may need to extend a specific superclass to do its primary job. The only superclass from which all possible Cloneable classes can inherit implementation is Object.

Cloning was defined long before generics.

Answer (score 1):

`clone()` method is unnecessary, every object could invoke `Object.clone` method by reflect, so an object can be cloned depends on whether to implement `Cloneable` interface. This is for a security reason. You can simply clone an object which implements `Cloneable` by this util:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Cloneable> T clone(Cloneable obj) {
    T rtn = null;
    try {
        Method method = Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("clone");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        rtn = (T) method.invoke(obj);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rtn;
}
```