# Why does Cloneable not have clone()?

Tags: java

I was trying to understand how Object.clone() works in Java. I came across the following facts:

- A class implements the `Cloneable` interface to indicate to the Object.clone() method that it is legal for that method to make a field-for-field copy of instances of that class.
- Invoking `Object`'s `clone` method on an instance that does not implement the `Cloneable` interface results in the exception `CloneNotSupportedException` being thrown.
- However, note that the `Cloneable` interface does not contain the `clone` method. Hence, implementing `Cloneable` is not responsible for raising any error / exception for not implementing `clone()`.
- Instead, `Object.clone()` is a native method, which [calls](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/45af329463a45955ea2759b89cb0ebfe40570c3f/jdk/src/share/native/java/lang/Object.c#L47) `JVM_Clone` [from `jvm.cpp`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/50bdefc3afe944ca74c3093e7448d6b889cd20d1/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#L545) and `CloneNotSupportedException` is [thrown](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/50bdefc3afe944ca74c3093e7448d6b889cd20d1/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#L566) in this cpp method.

**Doubts:**

**Q1.** Why did the Java designers make this design choice and implement it like this? Why not have `clone()` defined in `Cloneable` itself which will give a compile time error if the implementing class does not provide an implementation for `clone()`.

**Q2.** Why check whether an instance implements `Cloneable` at run time?

**Q3.** Is there any specific reason to check it in native code?

**Q4.** The weird thing is `Object` itself does not implement `Cloneable`, but provides an implementation of `clone()`, which in turn checks whether any class implementing `Cloneable` implements `clone()` or not. Shouldn't ideally `Object` implement `Cloneable` (declaring `clone()`) and then provide an implementation for `clone()`?

**PS:** I know asking multiple questions in one question is a bad idea. But these are closely related questions. I could very well ask a single question like "Why does `Cloneable` not contain `clone()`?" But, I felt, to better answer this doubt, one must cover various subtle aspects of this design decision. I gave effort to think more and came up with possible different subtle aspects and asked them explicitly pointwise so that an answerer wont miss them and will give an overall complete answer.

Comment: The short answer is: they made the terrible design choices long, long ago, before anybody knew any better, and now we're stuck with it being terribly designed forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Cloneable not deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398951/why-is-cloneable-not-deprecated)

Comment: because "modifier `native` not allowed" ..in an interface (..and `clone` *is* native...answers Q1-Q4)

Comment: Note: `Object.clone()` does not check whether a `Cloneable` class overrides `clone()` or not. It doesn't care. In practice, you almost always do need to override that method, to (1) make the method public, (2) suppress the useless checked exception that will never be thrown, (3) deep clone any fields. But it's not strictly required to override it and it is not checked.

Comment: One more doubt why `Object` declares `clone()` as `protected`? Every class is subclass of `Object`, so it will be visible to all classes, right? Is this another bad design decision?

Comment: If `clone()` were public, it would force every `Cloneable` class to keep that method public, to be publicly cloneable. By making the base method protected, a class can choose whether to be publicly cloneable, or to only allow clones that it creates itself. I've never seen a real use for it, but there is some theoretical logic behind it.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is that they wanted to provide a default implementation of the clone() method, but default methods didn't exist then, so they just had Object.clone and then the Cloneable interface to signify that it could be cloned. So it's really just that it's old.

As another user said before, the clone method is native and that modifier is also not allowed in interfaces. Making Cloneable an abstract class is not an option because you would be forced to extend it and not be able to extend other classes since Java doesn't really have multiple inheritance. Why clone isn't just supported for all objects, I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by " Object.clone can't really be overridden"? In eclipse, when we try to add `clone()` to our class, eclipse itself adds `@Overrides` to it.

Comment: @anir I'm sorry, I'll fix my answer. I meant that you can't do the native stuff involved in copying objects yourself.